# Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives

Tags: system-installation

I have two hard drives. One is used for Windows and one is empty. I want to install Ubuntu on the empty hard drive. The Windows hard drive is disk0 in Windows and the empty hard drive is disk1. When I install Ubuntu and it asks where I want to install it, I choose "Something Else" but I am stuck there. What do I choose for "boot loader installation"?

Comment: You want to install it side by side

Answer (score 5):

Put the boot loader (known as the GRUB) in the hard drive that you are installing Ubuntu on. If Windows is in `/dev/sda` put GRUB in the MBR of `/dev/sdb`. That is, do not put GRUB in `/dev/sdb1` or another partition.

In the BIOS set to boot from the Ubuntu drive. This may boot straight to Ubuntu at first. If that happens open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo update-grub`. From the next boot you should get the choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

See [How do I set up multiple HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181729/how-do-i-set-up-multiple-hdd/181841#181841)

Answer (score 1):

#### Installing Ubuntu on 2nd hard drive, Windows on 1st

- Unplug Windows hard drive.
- Install Ubuntu on second hard drive.
- Plug Windows drive back in.
- Set Ubuntu hard drive as the first HDD in BIOS.
- Boot Ubuntu hard drive.
- In Terminal run:

  ```
    sudo update-grub
  ```

This should automatically add a Windows menuentry to the grub boot menu.

You can change back to Windows bootloader, (first HDD), using BIOS if desired.

Comment: Thank you karel, my "code" button does not seem to be working. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Pressing the code button inserts 4 spaces in front of the selected text if it starts on a new line and 2 spaces after it. If the selected text is in the middle of the line it formats it as code inline. Either of these functions can be duplicated from the keyboard manually. If the code  is in as numbered or bulleted list then 8 spaces must be inserted before the code in order to position it correctly in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I connected up one drive and installed Ubuntu. Then disconnected the drive. Then connected another drive and installed Windows 7. Then I connected up both drives and in the Bios set the computer to boot from CD as 1 then the Windows 7 as 2 and lastly the Ubuntu drive. Now when I start up it boots into Windows 7 without any menu. When I want Ubuntu as it is booting up I press F11 and choose the hard drive Ubuntu is on.