# Install Ubuntu on a separate hard-drive in dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a hard-drive that is separate from the one Windows 7 is on. I have two drives in my computer and the second is unused and blank.

However, when I go to install Ubuntu and select the *Something Else* option, I get kind of paranoid. Last time I did this, it wiped my Windows drive and still installed in the second drive. I do now want a repeat of that.

If someone could give me instructions on dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 7 using two hard-drives that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the correct hard drive. Windows is almost certainly on sda and you will want to install on sdb. Install grub into the first hard drive.

If you do not know which drive has windows, use gparted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BIOS to select other HDD as primary, then install Ubuntu on it. Then from BIOS you can easily switch in between HDDs and boot into Windows or linux

Comment: The question is about setting up partitions on a second hard disk drive for the installation of Ubuntu. Selecting a HDD as primary has nothing to do with how a drive is partitioned and switching between HDDs in BIOS to boot either Windows/Linux is a moot point as grub should be able to handle both Windows and Linux even if they are on separate drives, providing they were both installed in UEFI or Legacy mode.