# Installation of Ubuntu on other HDD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

My Desktop configuration is Intel i5-2320,4GB RAM,Nvidia GeForce 520 GPU.I have two hard disks in my system. One is 500GB and other one is 1TB. I have dual-booted Windows XP and Windows 7 on 500GB HDD. I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 on a separate partition created on 1TB HDD. How can I do this installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu on a seperate hard-drive in dualboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313460/install-ubuntu-on-a-seperate-hard-drive-in-dualboot)

Comment: With two drives, best to have grub2's boot loader on MBR of second drive. All default installs overwrite the Windows boot loader on first drive. You can disconnect Windows drive, or use Something Else to manually install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: So I should use "something else" to manually put grub into Linux partition and go forward in installation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use the BIOS to set the second hard drive as the primary boot drive, then install Ubuntu and then use the BIOS menu to 'switch' between Ubuntu and Windows XP/7.  Easiest, keep both OSes separate on 2 different hard drives, no fuss!