# Why I am being taken to Windows 7 and can't boot into Ubuntu 13.04 after installation?

Tags: 13.04, windows-7, boot-repair

After finished installation I am not able to boot in to Ubuntu, I tried to use the Boot-Repair software, but I got no luck with the Recommended Repair.

So, as instructed, I type here the URL returned by the Boot-Repair program:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6028654/

Comment: I noticed you have the OSes on two different hard disks.This might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option

Comment: Also see [my answer to installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives).

Comment: This is a BootInfo URL with no repair. Have you tried the Recommended Repair?