# Dual Boot 2 separate SSD drives?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

So right now I only have 1 SSD in my computer.  It is 120 GB Samsung SSD.  I boot windows directly from this SSD.  I would like to buy another totally separate SSD and install and boot Ubuntu from this one.  So 1 PC, 2 drives, and boot windows 7 from 1, and boot Ubuntu from other SSD.  Is this possible?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: See my answer to the old [question about using 2 HDDs.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) Using SSD shouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This is exactly what I do on my laptop with two SSDs. One has Ubuntu, the other has Windows 7. I removed the Windows disk when I installed Ubuntu so I could guarantee nothing got written to it during the install.

During bootup I now just pick which drive I want to boot from.

Comment: But you didn't need to remove the Windows disk, right? I don't feel like reapplying my disk's thermal pads, which I would probably need to do.

Comment: Sure. I was just being careful.