# Install ubuntu on windows 8 on second hard drive without affecting setup

Tags: system-installation

Harddrives: 125 gb SSD with windows 8 installed, 1 tb hdd

What I want to do: I want to install ubuntu on my hdd without affecting my current set up too much. Right now windows 8 boots up nice and fast and I don't want to have to choose which operating system I want to use all the time. Is there a way to download ubuntu onto my hdd and launching it from windows when I want to use it? 
Thanks

Comment: Use [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to dual-boot your system is to install Ubuntu on a separate partition on your SSD.  The Ubuntu installer will help you do this.  It will also install a boot loader (probably GRUB) that will help you select which one you would like to boot after POST.  This will yield the best experience from both operating systems.

Comment: I'd be careful with that especially because OP is using windows 8 so he likely has some EFI boot setup pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download VMware for windows 8 that will allow you do what you want to do, You cannot run another OS from with in Windows OS with out Virtual PC software and I works just like it would if you booted up from the drive and you can switch between the two