# How can I get Ubuntu and Windows XP to dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside  Windows XP Home. Everything appeared to be progressing normally and I was prompted to eject the CD and reboot. The result was:

```
error: no such device: 1c8bea6b-44fd-4bef-b0cd-f1ef87666ec2
grub rescue>_
```

I typed `ls` and got this:

```
(hd0)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)(fd0)
```

The computer is a Dell Dimension 8250 desktop 1GB RdRAM Maxtor 40GB [C drive] WD 20GB [D drive] I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Window, and install Ubuntu to D (the only choice given).

I have downloaded and burned a bunch of utilities in anticipation of problems. The computer will still boot from the DVD (not the CD, I don't know why it was OK before).

Right now the computer is booted to a Linux graphical desktop environment (XFCE) [SystemRescueCD4.1](http://sysresccd.org)

One of the programs is something called Partimage:

```
  sda1    fat16     31.35 Mib   --- Windows recovery?
  sda2    ntfs      37.24 GiB   --- This is Windows (I think)
  sr1     unknown   0 bytes     --- What is this? (DVD drive maybe)
  sdb1    ntfs      5.58 Gib
  sdb2    extended  
  sdb5    ext3fs    12.53 GiB   --- This is Linux (I think)
  sdb6    swap(v1)  1024  MiB   --- Linux swap file
```

XFCE has a terminal mode where I hope I can type some cryptic magic words that will get Ubuntu and Windows dual booting as I intended.

I'm also wondering what wrong with this installation. Thanks very much to anyone who can help me figure out where to go from here.

Comment: See this [**answer**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863) and use the recommended repair option from the **Boot Repair.** Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives/193812#193812

Comment: @user68186 please do not post the answer inside the *question*. Take a time an write it on the *answer* section.

Comment: @Lucio I think you meant user256282 the original poster not me. I never post answers in questions.

Comment: ups, sorry. Your are right, I was talking to user256282 :)

Answer (score 0):

OP found this answer:

---------------  FOUND IT!  ----------------

setting in bios

Primary Drive 0 ........  Hard disk

Primary Drive 1 ........  OFF

changed OFF to AUTO ..... save and exit .....

boot continues and Hooray! there is my boot menu with
Linux and Win XP

Odd that I had to change something bios for a drive that
could be seen by Windows and Gparted to get grub to work right