# How can I create a dual boot, keeping in mind my pc boots to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, menu

So I got 2 new 500GB hard drives and I installed Windows 7 first on the first hard drive and on the second I installed 12.04 ubuntu.

Is there any software that I can use to make it easier to get a boot menu to choose the os that I want to boot into?

Comment: Does the default grub not do exactly that?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/)

Answer (score -2):

Try grub customizer via synaptic package manager. I use this for multi-boot systems.
A few years back I had a program on a cd called "super grub disk" that allowed one to boot-up any OS found on the pc. Try google as I cannot remember where I got it from. Hope this helps.