# Windows installed on one hard drive, Ubuntu on 2nd, how to choose between on boot?

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a Linux noob who had an extra 250GB Hard Drive lying around. I have Windows installed on my main 1TB Hard Drive, and I'm going to install Ubuntu on the second 250GB Hard Drive. What I want to know, is there a way to choose between the two on boot? Don't make fun of me, but on my old Macbook Pro I had Os X and Windows both installed, and I could hit a combination of keys during startup, and I could choose what OS to boot into. Is there a way to do that with Linux? If there are any programs I could install to give me that choice, please point me in the right direction! I've heard of a thing called GRUB, but I'm not really sure what it does. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install ubuntu on your other hard drive, it will (by default) automatically install grub, which is a bootloader. It will do exactly what you want. After installation, just go to your bios and set your default boot drive to the second one (with ubuntu install). When you boot you'll see a screen with a few different options to boot. It will look like this but with another option below to boot into windows:

[image]

It will by default boot into ubuntu after 10 seconds if no key is pressed, but you can just use the arrow keys to navigate and enter to choose whether to boot into windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome... Thank for the help! I'm so excited to start using Linux, it sounds like a great OS!

Comment: It is awesome, I have almost completely switched over. Had to switch back to windows for the first time in three weeks yesterday... Personally I like the gnome desktop more than the default unity, I recommend you look up Ubuntu Gnome and see if that interests you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu, it will install grub also. 
You have to do nothing. 
Grub will recognize both Windows and Ubuntu disks. 
You no need a combination of keys during boot. 
It will automatically load grub and will give you the option to select which OS you want to boot to.