# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04 on ssd

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have recently bought a Samsung 840 EVO 120gb SSD, I currently have Windows 7 installed and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04. In the installer I cant see the SSD in the dropdown menu (the one where you choose the hard drive for the installation) but if I try to specify the partitioning myself I can format the SSD and then allocate some space for Ubuntu. How can I install Ubuntu without losing my Windows 7 partition?

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You have Windows in the original HDD and you bought and installed a new SDD. You want to install Ubuntu in the new SDD without changing anything in the HDD. You have to use the "Something Else..." option and manually create the partitions in the SDD. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem properly...

The best would be first to arrange a separate partition for Ubuntu. If the entire disk is used now for Win7, you would need to shrink the Win7 partition by a chosen amount and then what's left use for Linux partition.

However - if you're not sure what you're doing there's a chance you may lose you windows data - so better be careful. Backup would be recommended.

To resize the partition(s) you can use gparted - it should be also in Ubuntu Live, which you can also use later to install your Ubuntu system on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your windows partition is expanded to fit the whole disk. this is a simple fix. Press start on your windows OS. then right click on computer, then, from the drop down, press manage. then press disk management. then find your C: drive that windows is installed on, right click it, and press shrink. Then, shrink the volume to an appropriate size. then reboot back into the ubuntu install. then click on "Something else" when you get to that point. Create a partition and mount it as /, then make another partition 4GB partition and mount it as swap (This is optional but it speeds up tasks such as booting and installing files) then continue with the installation.

Comment: Is the swap partition not only used when the system is out of memory? How should that speed up boot time?