# Dual booting machines

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

Is it possible to run a dual boot machine by installing Windows on one hard drive in the machine, and installing Ubuntu on a second hard drive inside the machine?

Comment: Yes. Install Ubuntu last so that grub will pickup windows and place it in the menu. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on one of two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives) and [Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629750/installing-ubuntu-on-second-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all. But you need to install Windows first so grub can identify it and add an entry for it in the menu.

You can find further information about dual booting here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot