# No boot option after UBUNTU 12.1 installation on another hard disk

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10  on my Windows XP SP3 GR desktop using ubuntu dvd from iso file. Operatings systems  are in diferent hard disks. After the install  I did not get the option of choosing OS and directly went to Windows XP. 
I think it has something to do with GRUB, but I'm not really sure.
Please help. 
Thank's

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/181729/how-do-i-set-up-multiple-hdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub2 probably got installed on the Ubuntu hard drive, while the machine is booting off the First (Windows) drive.  Change the boot order in BIOS to boot off the second hard drive first and you should either get a boot menu with both OS's listed, or it may boot directly into Ubuntu.

If it boots directly into Ubuntu then you should update the grub boot menu with the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: That's it. Grub got installed on the ubuntu hard drive, no on win Xp (boot) hard. A change in BIOS and ...solved